# Why does this Terraform managed AWS Cloudfront distribution give error 403 AccessDenied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I setup a Cloudfront distribution, S3 bucket, and associated policies as follows:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "front_end" {
  bucket = var.domain_name
  acl    = "public"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "front_end" {
  statement {
    sid = "AllowCloudFront"

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject"
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.front_end.arn}/*"
    ]

    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.main.iam_arn,
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "front_end" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.front_end.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.front_end.json
}

locals {
  origin_id = "tdweb-S3-origin"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "main" {
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.front_end.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id = local.origin_id

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.main.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }

  enabled = true
  is_ipv6_enabled = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  aliases = [
    var.domain_name,
  ]

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]

    cached_methods = ["GET", "HEAD"]

    target_origin_id = local.origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl = 0
    default_ttl = 86400
    max_ttl = 31536000
  }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.main.arn
    ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1"
  }

  custom_error_response {
    error_code = 403
    response_code = 200
    error_caching_min_ttl = 0
    response_page_path = "/"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "main" {
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "root_domain" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.external.zone_id
  name = var.domain_name
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = aws_cloudfront_distribution.main.domain_name
    zone_id = aws_cloudfront_distribution.main.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

and I get this when I access my website from the domain:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DHDW5R8Q8R8RFS1J</RequestId>
<HostId>CaKxdDjJ/azq9BUOePWsc1f/O+sLuoex4mtz57JbtAdAZe05v1Vwy+OjNehkiYGN2jeSOPMIO3o=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Following the debugging steps, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/, I have check what I think is all the possible issues.

> If you don't configure an origin access identity (OAI), then the
> objects must be publicly accessible or requested with AWS Signature
> Version 4.

I am using OAI.

> Objects in the bucket can't be encrypted by AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS).

I don't think they are. That's not enabbled.

> The S3 bucket policy must allow access to s3:GetObject. If the bucket policy
> grants access, then the AWS account that owns the S3 bucket must also own the object.

Yep, my policy does exactly that. There's also only one account involved.

> The requested objects must exist in the S3 bucket. If clients request the
> root of your distribution, then you must define a default root object.

Yep, I'm trying to get route and this config points to index.html which is in the bucket.

> If you configured an OAI, then the OAI must be included in the S3
> bucket policy. If you didn't configure an OAI, then Amazon S3 block
> public access settings must be disabled.

I did configure OAI to the best of my knowledge, this is the most likely culprit since I'm the least familiar with this step but I think it's configured. I followed the docs on the Terraform website so much of this is copied from there.

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Edit: this is the json generated by this terraform.

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "AllowCloudFront",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E2I7BV2A1PTW72"
},
"Action": "s3:GetObject",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
}
]
}

Comment: Could you post what the actual bucket policy in json format look like?

Comment: Sure. I just added it.

Comment: Ok, it looks good to me. Can you invalidate the CF distribution and try again?

Comment: Do you mean just disable it and then reenable it? Or is invalidate something different?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#Invalidation_Requests

Comment: Just do a `/*` invalidation

Comment: Oh that. Yes. I've done that a lot for /*. I'll run it now though.

Comment: I ran another. Still access denied.

Comment: Does the resource you are trying to access exists?

Comment: Yeah. There's currently just one item in the bucket and it's index.html.

Comment: @mmachenry Can you try to use S3 bucket ID as `origin_id` in `aws_cloudfront_distribution`? Like this: `origin_id   = aws_s3_bucket.front_end.id`

Comment: did you sort it out? having the same issue